# Compare column from a dataframa and put it in another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two data frames like this:

df1:

```
     col1    col2          time
0    A        A_1          05:02:03
1    A        A_2          15:36:14
2    A        A_1          28:21:47
3    A        A_1          47:21:17
4    A        A_1          52:28:01
5    A        A_2          72:27:14
```

I want to compare if the time in column "time" is <24h, >24 but <48, >48 but <72h and >72 and put these results to another dataframe like this:

df2:

```
     col1    col2          time <24       24<time<48       48<time<72    time>72
0    A        A_1              1              2               1             NaN
1    A        A_2              1              NaN             NaN            1
```

So, basically what I want in this df2 is to have the count of files that meet comparison, like for example there are two files in "time" column that belong to A and A_1 and the time is <24, and we just put 2 in the "time<24" folumns

EDIT:
Thanks @Andreas and @Nk03, it worked great when I had all the scenarios there, but for example when I don't have time that is >72 it is failing because that `'time3':'time>72'` it is not created and i get an error that says:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

How should i fix this one? When i have a dataframe and it doesnt have any value that is >72 or any doenst meet other comparisons. Lets say i have a dataframe like this.

df1:

```
     col1    col2          time
0    A        A_1          05:02:03
1    A        A_2          15:36:14
2    A        A_1          28:21:47
3    A        A_1          47:21:17
4    A        A_1          32:28:01
5    A        A_2          37:27:14
```

And still have this df2 desirable output:

```
   col1    col2          time <24       24<time<48       48<time<72   time>72
0    A        A_1              1              3             NaN        NaN
1    A        A_2              1              1             NaN        NaN
```

EDIT2:
This is the error im getting after puting that extra line in your answer:

```
df[list(set(d.values()).difference(df.columns))] = np.nan
```

[image: My dataframe]
[image: Error I'm getting]

Comment: why not just add another column with the time bin?  That will probably be a more useful format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the time by :, then divide the hours by 24 and round it. After that you can pivotize the whole dataframe. After that rename the columns in the way you want.

```
df['day'] = (df['time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)/24).astype(int)
df = df.pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'], columns=['day'], values=['time'], aggfunc='count').reset_index()

d = {'time0':'time <24', 'time1':'24<time<48', 'time2':'48<time<72', 'time3':'time>72'}
df.columns = [d.get(''.join(map(str, x)), ''.join(map(str, x))) for x in df.columns]

#   col1 col2  time <24  24<time<48  48<time<72  time>72
# 0    A  A_1       1.0         2.0         1.0      NaN
# 1    A  A_2       1.0         NaN         NaN      1.0
```

If you want to have a safety check afterwards to see if all columns are in there you can use this as last line:

```
for col in d.values():
    if col not in df.columns:
        df[col] = np.nan
```

Comment: Hey @Andreas, thanks for the answer. I edited the question, can you check?

Comment: @user14073111 hey, yes. I updated the answer

Comment: Hey @Andreas, i got an error with that extra line, can you check?

Comment: @user14073111 oh, maybe we have different python or pandas versions? Ok try, the one I just updated. Its longer but should be simpler.

Comment: I just realized that I had to update my jupyter notebook and that is why it was not working, it works perfectly now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Please modify the time-bin, if required:

```
df['time2'] = pd.cut(df.time.str.split(':').str[0].astype(int), bins=[-np.inf, 24, 48, 72, np.inf],
                     include_lowest=True, labels=['time <24', '24<time<48', '48<time<72', 'time>72'], right=False)
result = df.pivot_table(index=['col1', 'col2'],
                        columns='time2', aggfunc='count').reset_index()
```